# Warning: An exception of type 'System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException' occurred in System.Data.dll.

Tags: asp.net, sql-server

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eUfib.png)

I am having exception on my this line "SA.Fill(DS, "EmployeeDetails");". Its saying that its an Sql unhandled code. This table exist in my db and working perfectly.
Below is the preview of my DB.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NDOJT.png)

If anyone can please help me, it would be appreciated.

Comment: Put the relevant code and error message in your question as text, not images. It's hard to search images. It's hard to copy images into answers. And it's annoying to have to go somewhere else to understand your question. A picture is fine as a supplement to your question,  but it shouldn't be the only thing.

Comment: @mason i will be taking care it further ahead :) 
Thanks for pointing out!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You created your table in the wrong database, its in `master`. You can see that in your 2nd screen shot, at the very top left corner you see the active/selected database.

Master is a reserved system database, do not put your own objects in there.

So to be sure that you are interacting with your database in SSMS put this statement at the top of your query file

```
use EmployeesInfo
Go

-- and now you can do whatever
SELECT * FROM EmployeeDetails
```

Comment: Thankyou so much :)
I missed that out

Comment: But i am unable to create the database in System Databases Section..
Its not allowing me to create a database, however its asking to restore a database.

Comment: @S.Quratulain - that is correct, you should not be able to create any databases there. Those are reserved for the System. You can only create databases directly in the `Databases` container.

Comment: Oh yess @Igor
I haven't selected the EmployeesInfo DB while making query.

Comment: @S.Quratulain - Glad it worked for you. Please consider accepting an answer using the check mark next to it.